# Possible simple SQL Query

Tags: sql, oracle, where-in

I'm feeling stupid, as this should have a simple answer. Maybe I need more cooffe.

Imagine the following Oracle table:

| Row | ID1 | ID2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | B | B |
| 2 | B | A |
| 3 | C | A |
| 4 | C | B |
| 5 | D | A |
| 6 | D | B |
| 7 | E | A |

How can I select all the lines **except** ID1 = E, and the ones with ID2 = A and ID1 = B or C (meaning that I want all of ID1 = D, but for ID1 = B or C , to remove ID2 = A).
I can possible do it with a lot of OR, but is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I select all the lines except ID1 = E, and the ones with ID2 = A and ID1 = B or C (

This is boolean logic.  You would can use:

```
where not (id1 = 'E' or (ID2 = 'A' and ID1 IN ('B', 'C')))
```